# Falha ao carregar o recurso: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou começando a usar o VueJS e estou desenvolvendo um jogo, mas não consigo carregar as imagens salvas no meu PC na interface do jogo. Alguém pode consertar isso?

Aqui está o que eu tentei até agora:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <a href="#" @click.prevent="selectCart">
            <img src="virada.png" alt="baralho" class="carts">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div v-if="cartSelected =! ''">
            <img :src="'' + cartSelected +'.png'" alt="carta" class="cart">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: o src da primeira tag img está procurando por uma imagem na mesma pasta em que o arquivo que está esse código está. Tente colocar o caminho todo do diretório onde está a imagem caso ela não esteja no mesmo lugar de onde o arquivo está.

Comment: ja fiz isso, espeficiquei o caminho mas ainda assim não funcionou <img :src="'assets/carts/' + cartSelected +'.png'" alt="carta" class="cart">

Comment: @jessie use `<img :src="require('@/assets/carts/' + cartSelected + '.png')" />`